# How to write rails migration for multiple associations with same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to associate origin and destination port cities (stored in a Port model) with records in a Job model through named foreign keys.  I've scoured many examples of this type of relationship but I still can not insert new Port records via rails console.  The job is created before trying to create the ports records.  Here are the association definitions:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :destinations, :class_name => 'Port', :foreign_key => 'destination_id'
    has_many :origins, :class_name => 'Port', :foreign_key => 'origin_id'
end
class Port < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :origin, :class_name => "Job"
    belongs_to :destination, :class_name => "Job"
end
```

The schema (edited):

```
create_table "jobs", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "origin_id"
  t.integer  "destination_id"
  t.index ["destination_id"], name: "index_jobs_on_destination_id"
  t.index ["origin_id"], name: "index_jobs_on_origin_id"
end
create_table "ports", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.float    "lat"
  t.float    "lon"
end
```

I am looking for the exact syntax for foreign keys to use in the migrations that set up these models.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you getting an error or something? Showing the code you're using to insert it would also help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a little like you've got the relationships around the other way.

Presuming this is something like Shipping. There are many Ports in the world.
A Ship/Plane has many Jobs. A Job is between two Ports.

In this scenario,

```
class Job
  belongs_to :origin, class_name: "Port"
  belongs_to :destination, class_name: "Port"
end

class Port
  has_many :origin_jobs, class_name: "Job", foreign_key: "origin_id"
  has_many :destination_jobs, class_name: "Job", foreign_key: "destination_id"
end
```

Creating records in console could be done like so

```
origin_port = Port.first
destination_port = Port.second
Job.create(origin: origin_port, destination: destination_port)
```